# flutter `StateError (Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist)` when trying to show userdata

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i was trying to show/retrieve user data from firebase to my profile page in my app, but i get the error

```
StateError (Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist)
```

i dont know why this error existed as i already match the name of field to my Firebase, in the emulator it shows a `null` inside the email decoration.

Here's my profile page code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';

import '../Reminder/ui/theme.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});



  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  String? email;
  String? fullName;
  String? birth;
  String? bloodType;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    getProfile();
    super.initState();
  }

  getProfile() async{
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get();

      setState(() {
        email = userDoc.get('email');
        fullName = userDoc.get('full name');
        birth = userDoc.get('date of birth');
        bloodType = userDoc.get('blood type');

      });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Profile',
          style: headingStyle,
        ),
        backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 120,
                    height: 120,
                    child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/profile.png")),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Form(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                       Container(
                        height: 40,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.person),
                            SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text(email.toString())
                          ],
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black26,

                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))
                        ),
                       ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 100,
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                            },
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            child: Text('SIGN OUT'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
    );
  }
}
```

if you guys know how to fix it, please help me. it would mean so much to me, thankyou guys

Comment: Hey did you try this  email = userDoc.data()["email"];.

Comment: got this error when i hover the 'email' ```The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'```

Comment: You can type cast object like  final infoMap = userDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic> and then try String? email = infoMap["email"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when your document is null OR the field `email` you are trying to access is not available in the document.

I recommend you to check whether any document in `users` collections with the provided `user.uid` exists or not and check whether the expected fields are there. Also check whether the user is actually logged in using `print(user.email)` to verify that all checks out.

For information follow [this flutterfire example](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/profile.dart) best practices on this auth flow

Comment: how do i check if collections with the provided ```user.uid``` exist?

Comment: @NyK No I mean collection named with `users` in your [firebase console](https://firebase.corp.google.com/) and check if it contains the document with id `user.uid` (not exactly that I mean user with that uid) you can get that using print(user.uid) in your app.

Comment: Did this help your query ? please feel free to reach out in case you need any further clarification.